# Setting Multiple Titles for subplots in loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib

I would like to generate a plot title for each of my 4 subplots within a loop. For any reason,
only the last element of the name and freq list is used and the for loop does not iterate through the two list in dependance of p. Any ideas how to solve this ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'],['4']]
freq = ['51', '52', '53','54']
supplier = ['A', 'B']

fig1, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
for p in range(4):
    [axs[l, k].set_title('Curves for '+ name[p][0] + '\n by ' + supplier[k] + '@ ' + freq[p]) for l in range(2) for k in range(2)]
plt.show()
```

This is what is generated now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wxCx.png)

The expected output should be like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzSDL.png)

Comment: Hi @sts - you have 3 for loops, which are running for 2x2x4 = 16 times. So, the plots are getting overwritten and you are seeing only the last runs... what are the 4 titles you are expecting?

Comment: Hi @Redox - I have added a link to the plot which should be the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this helps.

You need to run the loop just once and control the positions by just using `p` and run it from 0-3. Other variables used are not really required. Looks to be in line with what you put up in the figure. Let me know in case of questions...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'],['4']]
freq = ['51', '52', '53','54']
supplier = ['A', 'B']

fig1, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
for p in range(4):
    [axs[int(p/2), int(p%2)].set_title('Curves for '+ name[p][0] + '\n by ' + supplier[int(p%2)] + '@ ' + freq[p])]# for l in range(2) for k in range(2) for p in range(2,4)]
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]